# Each Preimage of an Evenly Covered Open set is a Component

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, covering-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $q : X \to Y$ be a continuous map.

An open set $U \subseteq Y$ is said to be *evenly covered* by $q$ iff $q^{-1}[U]$ is a union of disjoint nonempty connected open sets $U_{\alpha} \subseteq X$, each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $q$.

I want to show that each $U_{\alpha}$ is a connected component of $q^{-1}[U]$.

A *connected component* of a topological space is a maximal connected subset, i.e., a connected subset $S$ such that every proper superset of $S$ is disconnected.

Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very unusual of definition of "evenly covered". The standard definition is

> An open set $U \subset Y$ is said to be *evenly covered* by $q$ iff $q^{-1}[U]$ is a union of disjoint nonempty open sets $U_{\alpha} \subset X$, each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $q$.

Your requirement that all $U_\alpha$ must be connected is equivalent to $U$ being connected (since each $U_\alpha \approx U$). Thus in the sense of your definition only connected $U$ have the chance to be evenly covered.

In spaces like $\mathbb Q$ there do not exist connected open sets, hence no evenly covered subsets. But don't you think that the projection $q :  \mathbb Q \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$ deserves to be called a covering map?

But okay, for spaces like manifolds your definition works well.

Let us now prove that the $U_\alpha$ are the connected components of $q^{−1}[U]$.

1. Each connected component $C$ of $q^{−1}[U]$ is contained in a unique $U_{\alpha_C}$.
   Let $A = \{ \alpha \mid C \cap U_\alpha \ne \emptyset \}$. Pick any $\alpha_C \in A$. Since all $U_\alpha$ are open in $X$, the set $V = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A \setminus \{\alpha_C\}} U_\alpha$ is open in $X$. Clearly $C = C \cap  \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha = C \cap U_{\alpha_C} \cup C \cap \bigcup_{\alpha \in A \setminus \{\alpha_C\}} U_\alpha =  C \cap U_{\alpha_C} \cup C \cap V$. The sets $C \cap U_{\alpha_C}$ and $C \cap V$ are open in $C$, disjoint and cover $C$. Since $C$ is connected and $C \cap U_{\alpha_C}$ is non-empty, we must have $C \cap V = \emptyset$ which implies that $A \setminus \{\alpha_C\} = \emptyset$, i.e. $C \subset U_{\alpha_C}$.
2. Each $U_\alpha$ is a connected component of $q^{−1}[U]$.
   Since $U_\alpha$ is connected, it is contained in a unique connected component $C$ of $q^{−1}[U]$. By 1. we have $C \subset U_{\alpha_C}$ and therefore $U_\alpha \subset U_{\alpha_C}$. This is possibly only if $\alpha = \alpha_C$. Hence $U_\alpha \subset C \subset U_\alpha$, i.e. $U_\alpha = C$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually the definition I wrote is the definition in John M. Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* (p.278). I forgot mentioning the reference. I think this book uses this definition because its main interest is topological manifolds.